# Edit the output of a filter

Tags: permalinks, filters

I'm trying to edit the output of the filter (below) in the plugin WPJobManager. I want to make sure there isn't a duplicate company_name value in the $job_slug before it is updated. At the moment, its set to add company_name to the slug, but if you then edit the same post, it adds company_name again!

```
if ( apply_filters( 'submit_job_form_prefix_post_name_with_company', true ) && ! empty( $values['company']['company_name'] ) ) {
        $job_slug[] = $values['company']['company_name'];
}
```

I think I need to add a filter in my functions.php but I'm not sure how to do this with an IF statement to remove the duplicate. I was thinking something like this below? Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
if ( strpos( $job_slug, sanitize_title($values['company']['company_name'];) ) ) {
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Looking at the code [here](https://github.com/Automattic/WP-Job-Manager/blob/master/includes/forms/class-wp-job-manager-form-submit-job.php), I'm not sure this is the source of your issue. The `$job_slug` is initialized as an empty array at line 756 (as of this writing), and the company name only gets prepended once.

Comment: Also, that filter passes only a boolean value, so `$job_slug` and `$values` aren't automatically available to any function you hook to it.

Comment: Thanks for the help Pat. I just want to stop the company name being added automatically again after the job is edited. Perhaps it's a bug with the plugin?

Comment: It might be. Your best bet is to contact the plugin's support team.

Answer (score 0):

i have created the following solution, it is working when you keep into the active theme functions.php.

**Refrence**
**Page:** includes\forms\class-wp-job-manager-form-submit-job.php
**Line:** 791

```
add_filter('submit_job_form_save_job_data', 'remove_dublicated_post_name', 10, 5);

function remove_dublicated_post_name($job_data, $post_title, $post_content, $status, $values){
 if( ! strpos( $job_data['post_name'] , sanitize_title($values['company']['company_name'] ) ){
    // to remove dublicate company names
    $post_name_raw_arr = explode("-",$job_data['post_name']);
    $post_name_unique_arr = array_unique($post_name_raw_arr );
    $job_data['post_name'] = sanitize_title( implode( '-', $post_name_unique_arr ) );
  }
return $job_data;
}
```